# MLFlow sklearn autologging prints too many info messages in colab

Tags: python, mlflow

I am trying mlflow sklearn auto logging, in colab, mlflow prints a lot of info messages and at times it crashes the browser. Attaching the pic of info logs[image: mlflow info logs]

codes are in [this colab file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wvHSgYk6boKW0AMPqIt-AByyFHSO26wm?usp=sharing)

Am not sure what am missing here, but the same code works fine without producing these info logs on my local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with MLFlow package, in which a hotfix has been raised.

See here: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/pull/3978

**Description of fault**

In MLflow 1.13.0 and 1.13.1, the following Python event logging message is emitted when a patched ML training function begins execution within a preexisting MLflow run.

Unfortunately, for patched ML training routines that make child calls to other patched ML training routines (e.g. sklearn random forests that call fit() on a collection of sklearn DecisionTree instances), this event log is printed to stdout every time a child is called.

This can produce hundreds of redundant event logging calls that don't provide value to the user.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me to this PR & fault description, spot on :) I underpinned MLFlow to 1.12.1 and it's not producing redundant logs :)